# Advice for running IAR Embedded Workbench for Arm with Dongle in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, iar

I am running Ubuntu 10.04 and Wine 1.2. I was able to install the IAR software but it is unable to locate the dongle license. Is there anyway to use a dongle license in Wine with Ubuntu or do I have to use a PC license?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

IAR doesn't support running it's software on linux,
I have read somewhere that someone was able to launch IAR embedded workbench for MSP430 using wine.

Regarding the license, as far as I remember, you just need to enter the serial number and the code that goes with it.

Comment: You can run the IDE in Wine, but it is little better than VisualStudio 1999 version. Still the compiler does not work, because the license manager does not work in Wine, it even pops up a dialog that says it does not run in any VM too.